# Transpose multiple rows into column in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I want to use transpose formulae in this data

[image: Input]

and I want desire output will look like this

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:B, "select max(B) where A is not null group by B pivot A")
```

[image: 0]

---

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(
 {SUBSTITUTE(A2:A, " ", "♥"), B2:B}, 
 "select max(Col2)
  where Col1 is not null
  group by Col2
  pivot Col1"),,999^99)), " ")), "♥", " "))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: great, It's working fine. can we paste the format also, any option  ??